# Using ffmpeg to cut video into pieces

Tags: ffmpeg

If using ffmpeg to precisely cut up a video into pieces, for instance using something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 0 -to 30 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -c:a copy p_1.mkv
```

Would the resulting clip include the last frame? (e.g., frame 1800 for a 60FPS video)

Also, should the audio also be re-encoded to ensure that no audio de-sync happens  if I were to concatenated it together with other clips?

Answer (score 0):

If the video is constant-frame-rate, then it should include 1800 frames. `to` stops when the position is reached i.e. `30.000` So, the 1800th frame in a CFR video will have a PTS of 29.983 s

As for audio, if the audio is shorter than the video, it will be so even after encode unless you expressly apply padding. Since you seem to be extracting from inside larger videos, you shouldn't encounter that problem.